# Calculating difference between z-value and elevation

Tags: arcgis-pro, z-value

I have a project in ArcGIS Pro, with DEM file implemented, so I have the elevation figures. Next, I have a polygon, that has certain z-value inserted (non-constant, varies from point to point). Now, I'd like to calculate the difference between ELEV and this z-value for given point/polygon (averaged). What tool should I use, or what approach should I take? Let's say, I have points/polygons, where these differences should be measured, already defined. I have two (empty, so far) attributes: (avg) height, and HGTdiff.

[image: IMG]

Comment: Sorry for my paint skills, but this is what I mean: https://ibb.co/t8NxZQN

Comment: @Hornbydd done, thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear if your want to generate Z value differences for the vertices of your polygon or the area of the polygon, suggest you explore the [Add Surface Information tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm)

Comment: Polygon (shaded blue) is correctly z-value attributed. I have elevation data, as it's seen on the 3D image. Now, I want to get a z value difference in any selected point/area (NOT related to any already exisiting polygon). Let's say I have these points defined in another multipoint feature class.

Comment: I've never had to extract an elevation from a 3D feature, may be you could convert it to a raster? Someone else may have a better idea? As for sampling from rasters you can use the [Sample tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sample.htm).

Comment: Ground (elevation) is indeed Raster/DEM. 3D Feature Polygon is added in arcGIS. Not sure if converting this polygon to raster is what I meant, But I could try it (if there's a function to do so?). Then, question is, how to compare two Raster heights.